# Share image in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I want to share an image in my app . I just have have an image in my xaml whose source is set at runtime by making canvas as bitmap.I want to share that image whose source is set at runtime.

Here is my c# code

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);
        myImg.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
    }
```

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871370.aspx) example share an image from installed location , How do I modify that to share my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert bitmap into RandomAccessStream then use that stream using SetBitmap Method:

```
args.Request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));
```

full code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested+= MainPage_DataRequested;
}

private async void MainPage_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);

    // 1. Get the pixels
    IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

    // 2. Write the pixels to a InMemoryRandomAccessStream
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);

    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96,
        pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    stream.Seek(0);

    // 3. Share it
    args.Request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));
    args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "description";
    args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "title";
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

SOURCE: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20648.using-the-rendertargetbitmap-in-windows-store-apps-with-xaml-and-c.aspx